# Loading PDF in IFrame in IE6 and IE7

Tags: html, css, pdf, cross-browser

I am loading a PDF inside of an IFrame inside of a popup window.

I have the PDF loading correctly in IE6 and IE7 - however there is an issue I am trying to solve.

When I load the PDF in the IFrame within IE7, and I resize the window from the right side of the window horizontally, the PDF does not scale down the window will resize down to where I cant see the whole width of the PDF. If I resize from the bottom corner of the window, the PDF resizes/scales horizontally just fine.

In IE6, when I resize from the right side of the window horizontally, the PDF rescales correctly, and also from the bottom corner.

Any idea why the PDF is not scaling down when I resize from right side of popup window in IE7? Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is my HTML for the IFrame:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        }
        html, body {
     width:100%;
        height: 100%;
     overflow:hidden;
        }
        #container{
        min-height: 100%;
        }
        * html #container {
        height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmMine" runat="server">
        <div>
            <iframe style="min-height:500px;min-width:100%; max-width:100%;height:auto !important;" id="iframe" runat="server"></iframe>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function resizeIframe() {
            var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            height -= document.getElementById('iframe').offsetTop;
            height -= 5;
            document.getElementById('iframe').style.height = height + "px";
        };
        document.getElementById('iframe').onload = resizeIframe;
        window.onresize = resizeIframe;
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE6 not supporting `min-`/`max-` might explain the discrepancy.  As for actually accomplishing what you want, is there some reason you're not using just `* { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0; }`?